# Why 'rails s' doesn't work with 127.0.0.1 but only with localhost on my Rails 5 project ? (I'm using MacBook Pro M1 2020)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a Rails 5 project (using a MacBook Pro M1 2020) and when I run `bundle exec rails s` I can't access to the page with 127.0.0.1 but only localhost.

It isn't problematic until I run the tests. The ones that need to make requests (using Capybara) do not pass. I have this error message :

Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:65155/etc' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status

Could someone help me with that please ?

Comment: Check if something is already running on port 3000 with this command `lsof -i :3000`.  This will return a table and the `PID` column will have process ids if something is using that port.  You can also find out using the Network Utility which comes with macOS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Nothing is running on port 3000. Moreover I can run a server on port 3000 but not on 127.0.0.1

Comment: I asked because sometimes I run a rails server but when I run rails again it is different about what addresses it listens to.